# How do I access subdirectories from a URL Frame

Tags: domains, dns, cname

I'm using Namecheap as my registrar, and I'm hosting my page with Microsoft Azure using a linux instance. The page is hosted at `<mysite>.cloudapp.net`. If I change the CNAME `www` record within Namecheap's manage domains to `<mysite>.cloudapp.net` I can use my domain to access the page but it reads `www.<mydomain>.org` when I want just `<mydomain>.org` (naked domain). When I use Namecheap's  recommended method of using a URL Frame instead of URL Redirect or CNAME record, the address appears correctly, but I can't access any subdirectories- e.g. `<mysite>.org/subdirectory/` will not work when `<mysite>.cloudapp.net/subdirectory/` does load the intended page.

Any help will be appreciated, and I'll provide any further clarification required.

Comment: CNAME records can't point to www and non-www: technically they are two different domains.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a *custom domain*.   [Microsoft has documentation for custom domain](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) setup when using a server from their cloud app.

You would have to:

- Point the domain name to the cloudapp.net server using a CNAME or A record

Since you get your own cloud app server with your own IP address, you don't even have to do any virtual host configuration.